# Is there any limit to the number of Selenium RCs connected to a Selenium Hub?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

Does anybody have experience using 20/50/100 RCs connected to a single Selenium Hub? I'm thinking of a centralized hub that multiple team could use together.

I heard that after 20 RCs, performance goes down significantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My tests use 104 RCs which are connected to a single Hub. Hub is able to handle all the RCs and the system is stable. One thing that you should note is, how you pass the commands to the Hub.This determines how much RCs Hub is going to utilize. What we do in our grid is, we run multiple builds at the same time - all pointing to the same Hub. This would mean Hub is always kept busy.

Comment: out of curiosity - what is your maxinstance and maxsession configuration for that number of nodes? i am curious how many actual sessions the grid can manage in parallel ...

Comment: @Kenn Max session and instance were 4 per VM.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where the "20" value is coming from.  I run with significantly more than that to power [Mogotest](http://mogotest.com/) and we run many more test sessions across various sites than most users of grid.  Granted older versions had some thread problems, but 1.0.8 should be pretty solid and the 2.0 releases have not exhibited any problems.

FWIW, I maintain the grid project and backport any known fix for any known load issues.  I also know of several others running large-scale grid installations without incident.

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to how robust your h/w is. Though I can't say exact statistics yet suggest to keep it with in 20

Answer (score 0):

Well there is not but yes very much close to 20 for good performance.